# Puppeteer is it only used for chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, puppeteer

Puppeteer is it only used with chrome browser ? what about the others ?

Answer (score 5):

Puppeteer is a browser test automation Node.js library that provides a high-level API to control headless Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol.

[Since Puppeteer 3.0, however, supports Firefox, a move that is poised to increase its usage for cross-browser testing purposes](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

[Microsoft Edge is built upon Chromium so it's supported too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/puppeteer/).

Answer (score 2):

As iamdlm pointed Firefox is also available in puppeteer.

If you are looking for a similar browser automation API that supports more than puppeteer there is also [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) from Microsoft.

The core API matches puppeteer's in 90% and there are more browser testing targeted methods additionally. The reason they are this similar: it is written by the ex-puppeteer team (after they moved to Microsoft from Google).

**It supports:**

- Chrome/Chromium (+ Edge, Opera, Chromium-based browsers)
- Firefox
- Webkit (Safari)

Their Firefox and Webkit use so-called "jugglers" - patched binaries of the original browsers. (Puppeteer's Firefox implementation is different, it is communicating to a real Firefox Nightly binary)

Example of browser usage in Playwright:

```js
// @ts-check
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Try to add 'firefox' to the list ↓
  for (const browserType of ['chromium', 'webkit']) {
    /** @type {import('playwright').Browser} */
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

[source: try.playwright.tech](https://try.playwright.tech/?e=page-screenshot)